# Can't call activex methods when the activex is in the same page as flash player

Tags: javascript, flash, com, atl

I created a customized ActiveX control and exposed a method called `getDesktopWindows`. Then I use the following javascript to call it:

```
var plugin = document.getElementById("myPlugin");
var wins = plugin.getDesktopWindows();
```

So far everything works just fine. Then I wrapped the code into a javascript function and use a flex application to call it.

In Javascript:

```
function getDesktopWindows() {
    var plugin = document.getElementById("myPlugin");
    var wins = plugin.getDesktopWindows();
    return wins;
}
```

In Flex:

```
var wins = ExternalInterface.call("getDesktopWindows");
```

Now I'll receive "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Guessing the problem would be because the call is originated from flash player. I tryed call it directly in javascript. And again I received the same exception. So may it because there're two activex present in the same webpage?

Comment: it's a ATL control. However I've managed to solve this. A lot thanks for checking this. Regards

BTW i‘ve posted this on MSDN forum and you also replied there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the call needs to be async. If a call has been initiated from an ActiveX and calls to another ActiveX, it fails in some browsers. The solution is to first queue the call, then initiate another call to the other ActiveX.